# Angular-TS designing model classes

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a page with a drop-down box and two input box elements. This drop-down has 8 values to select from. The two inputs are associated with each one of the the drop-down values, except one of the drop-down value display a popup window which has a table with 10 rows & 4 columns (fixed), each row has a check box and 3 input boxes (2 of them are same as the parent page plus one extra).

User should be able to select one or more check box(es) and fill-in input boxes. If the user was selected 4 check boxes, I should show the table in the parent page on save.

I have a model class for the drop-down box value (id & string). I have a model class for the 10 check boxes (id & string). How should I design the main model class as one of the value has 1:M relationship? Should I keep a separate array of objects? In that case, how do I attach it with the main model class? Thanks.

Model1 - For drop-down
id: number
text: string

Model2 - For check boxes
id: number
text: string

Model3 - For popup window
id: number
text: string (checkbox)
text1: string
text2: string
text3: string

MainModel
id: number
m1Id: number
m2Id: number
text1: string
text2: string
arrayObj: Model3??

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aa0FM.png)

Comment: That's a fair chunk of text to try and puzzle through to get a relevant picture of what you're trying to accomplish. Could you slap in something graphical, even a simple napkin (mspaint) drawing of what it's supposed to look like? Maybe it's just because it's bed time that my brain doesn't want to see what is happening...

Comment: I just edited my original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I gotcha.

The wonders of Angular; you don't need to reduce your self to such basic models. You can have a single, rich model and pick the relevant fields to populate the relevant components (i.e. id/string for a dropdown option).

It *seems* like, other than the number of text entries (2 or 3) and the additional application of a check box, every dropdown option is essentially the same.

Edit:

Removed allllllll that code with a myriad of errors due to changing my mind so often in favour of a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bs18rn?file=src/app/app.component.ts) example.

Can't make silly mistakes if you have a compiler yelling at you.

Comment: Thanks much. I didn't expect any code :). I will try and let you know.

Comment: In the SomeService class, I get below compilation error for the input "checkInput: undefined". The error message is type undefined is not assinable to type InputOption<boolean>.

I tried checkInput: boolean = false and it doesn't resolve the compilation error.
When I tried a non-null assertion like checkInput: undefined!, this error is gone but I see errors in "textInputs:" array. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Odd that it won't allow undefined, but you can solve that by make it an optional field for the `SomeModel` interface. Just change `checkInput: InputOption<boolean>;` to `checkInput?: InputOption<boolean>;` and it should allow you to assign as undefined. Note, however, that you can't assign checkInput to true/false because it's not a boolean type, it's an `InputOption<boolean>` type, so you'd have to assign it as a full object `checkInput = {text: 'click me', value: false};`

Comment: Thank you. I also had to change there isn't any interface called "TextInput". textInputs: TextInput<string>[]; to textInputs: InputOption<string>[]; In the html code, it doesn't recognize below line as it actually points to InputGroup interface. "let input of selectedOption.textInputs". I changed it to "let input of selectedOption.inputFields[0].textInputs". I get "cannot read property '0' of undefined' at runtime.

Comment: I even tried nested ngFor, it couldn't find "textInputs" array.

Comment: Removed all that horribly hand-written and obviously not checked code for a simple StackBlitz example - that works!

Comment: awesome! I learned some new stuff. Thanks a lot.